# Could I get a direct element in javascript using queryselector and foreach?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a **confirmation control** which I could use multiple times on a page if I would like to. Therefor I used HTML, Bootstrap and JavaScript. I would like to refrain from jQuery (as much as possible) for debugging reasons (I know for Bootstrap I still might need to use some of it still).

My **solution** contains `element.parentNode` in order to keep the controls separated when clicked on. The problem I am having is that I seem to be unable to get a specific button from the control when clicked on. My intention is to keep my code clean by using `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`, but I seem unsuccessful:

```js
const targetModal = $("#bs-modal-xl");
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-success");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".bar").forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));

  //How do I get the direct button containing the text "confirm?" after clicking any yes button and enable it?
  console.log(thisNode.parentNode.parentNode)
  console.log(thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("> button")); // returns Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '> button' is not a valid selector.
  console.log(thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("button")); // <-- returns nodelist of 3 buttons: "yes", "no" and "confirm?".
  console.log(thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".confirmation-box > button")); // <-- returns nodelist of the available "confirm?" buttons, in this case 2 of them.

  //I would not want the seperate ".confirmation-box" elements to interact with each other, these are independant elements.
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add("btn-warning");
  this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".foo").forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
}));
```

```css
#foo-container {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="foo-container">
  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success foo">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning bar">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" disabled>Confirm?</button>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success foo">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning bar">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" disabled>Confirm?</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ew06cbg/)

The controls are being separated by using my own custom element containing the class `.confirmation-box`.

The **desire** of the control is that when "yes" is clicked, the "confirm?" button's disabled state should be removed whereas "no" is clicked, should disable the "confirm?" button.

Is it possible to get the desired element using `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`? Could I refrain from looping (and using indexes) and use these methods instead? Am I overlooking something?

The desired element should look something like this: On click -> this -> find parent `.confirmation-box` element -> find child "confirm?" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess like this

```
const confirmButton = thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".confirmation-box > button");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get by the class:

```
thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".btn-danger")
```

```js
const targetModal = $("#bs-modal-xl");
const positiveNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
const negativeNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");

positiveNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const thisNode = this;
  thisNode.classList.add("btn-success");
  thisNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".bar").forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-warning"));

  //How do I get the direct button containing the text "confirm?" after clicking any yes button and enable it?
  console.log(thisNode.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".btn-danger"));
}));

negativeNodes.forEach(node => node.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add("btn-warning");
  this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".foo").forEach(node => node.classList.remove("btn-success"));
}));
```

```css
#foo-container {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="bs-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="foo-container">
  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success foo">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning bar">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" disabled>Confirm?</button>
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="confirmation-box">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success foo">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning bar">No</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" disabled>Confirm?</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, however when you change the class to make it look differently will break the code. I guess your solution then would be adding a specific class and then call for it.